# What is synonym of education in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

What is synonym of *education* in this sentence?

> **Education** is the single most important factor in the development of a country.

(The sentence is part of an IEST where I have to argue about the meaning and importance of education and I want to use different expressions.)

The word I want is the methodologies and facilities used to deliver knowledge to people. Usually this knowledge delivery is mainly aimed to schoolchildren and university students. I start to think that there is no synonym or even short phrase to describe education.

Someone suggest **schooling** as a synonym, but it applies to education at school, and we need to include the whole system including universities and further education.

Comment: And *education* doesn't fit because...? *Schooling* doesn't necessarily refer to education at school, by the way.

Comment: because it is IELTS exam and I want to use synonyms as possible :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to think you should try to maximise your use of "synonyms". In reality, there are very few *truly* synonymous word-pairs in English, and as a non-native speaker you'll probably often end up using several different terms for "the same thing", where actually only one of them was really the best choice for the specific context. Which in practice might simply call attention to the fact that you don't understand the relevant differences very well.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to when you use *education*? Government agencies responsible for academic institutions (or just the institutions themselves)—or the acquisition of knowledge?

Comment: all of these as I want to talk about ...well "the education".

Answer (score 2):

Schooling can be used but it does not really apply to colleges and universities. Education is the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

https://de.langenscheidt.com/deutsch-englisch/ausbildung

the term might be looking for could be
in german it would be "Bildung", this is  used for all degrees of schooling and "bringing up" people to knowledge, in french the expression the translation of Bildung is as well "formation/education.

If "formation" is used in English in the same way as in french it may fit most to solve your problem.

In your essay you could also introduce  the terms for "education" used in other languages and cultures, and then apply those as e.g. the term of the aztecs ("tlacahuapahualiztli") as it's "usus" in general:
"The Aztecs also had a well-developed theory about education, which has an equivalent word in Nahuatl called tlacahuapahualiztli. It means "the art of raising or educating a person"[8] or "the art of strengthening or bringing up men."[9] This was a broad conceptualization of education, which prescribed that it begins at home, supported by formal schooling, and reinforced by community living."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education